# Contact Form - From field

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I have a contact form on my website and sometimes emails sent through this form are going in spam folder. I think the problem is "from" field used in the header of the sent email. In that field is the email address entered by user.
Is it a good practice to use for "from" field a address like contact@mywebsite.com and to use just in reply-to field address of the sender? Or what other solution can be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion using contact@mywebsite.com in the from field is no problem as it comes from the contact page of your website. No problems imo.

Comment: What if the user has to insert his/her own e-mail address in the form? in the `mail()` statement I've tried `""-f myserver.myhost.com"` but then the mail won't send..

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why emails can be marked as spam.

Do you have a reverse dns name setup again the up address of the mail server? Many mail servers check this first

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for e-mails being marked as spam. The most common that is easily resolvable is called Forward Confirm(s) Reverse DNS.

This basically means that a DNS lookup of the mail server you're sending from e.g. mywebsite.com resolves to an IP: 1.2.3.4.

If in the ARPA `in-addr.arpa` (IPv4) lookup your resolved IP 1.2.3.4 resolves to mywebsite.com, you have passed this most basic step. If you hadn't already done this you may have already had your mailserver blacklisted, so check with the various search engines and tools available on the web.

Here is a tool for checking:

http://multirbl.valli.org/